# Remove or strip html tags and put them back again at the same position for a php string

Tags: php, html, string, preg-replace, preg-match

I was looking for a way to remove html tags from a string and put them back at the same position after sending the string to translate with deepL (which doesn't work with html tags in case they have attributes).

I'll post the solution bellow.

Comment: if you use deepl via their rest API then you can set on your calls `'tag_handling': 'xml',` and specify a non-translatable tag with eg `'ignore_tags': 'x'` then in your payload wrap the bits you want to skip with that tag: `<x>Dinsdale Piranha</x> And now for something completely different!`; another option is to use the experimental html mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLUTION:

Here's how you guys can remove and recover all the html tags in the same order in case you need to translate the string with DeepL like me or do something else which needs no html tags at the string.

https://gist.github.com/miguelgisbert/7ef9ee15aa0cc1ba32ea5ed192e486c3

```
$str1 = "<p style='color:red;'>red</p><strong style='color:green;'>green</strong>";
$pattern = '/<[^>]+>/';

preg_match_all($pattern, $str1, $matches);
$replacements = $matches[0];
$str2 = preg_replace($pattern, '<>', $str1);

// TRanslate $str2 with DeepL or do whatever without html tags

$str3 = preg_replace_callback('/<>/', function($matches) use (&$replacements) {
    return array_shift($replacements);
}, $str2);

echo "str1 ".$str1."<br>";
echo "str2 ".$str2."<br>";
echo "str3 ".$str3."<br>";
```

Comment: Nice approach! love that. For simpler things you can also use DeepLs tag handling on the API -> https://www.deepl.com/de/docs-api/html/

Comment: Hi Tim, I did, but the DeepL html tag handling seems to work wrongly when the tags have attributes, at least at the point I tried it. That's on beta status.

Comment: Got any more details about that? What you would have expected?

Comment: Is that the html tag attributes are not respected when the translation is made so the style or formatting is lost.

Comment: Hey Miguel, could you give me an example maybe? We are making some changes and updates to that functionality and would be good to know if we covered your case here as well

Comment: For example, for the following text (prestashop product description edited with the backoffice default prestashop editor) the first tags will be added to the translation properly but not the ones that have style="whatever" attribute nor the ling with the href attribute: 

<p><span>El más <strong>económico</strong> de los <em>somieres</em>. <span style="text-decoration: underline;">Reforzado</span> con una <span style="text-decoration: line-through;">barra</span> central <a href="https://pre.ventamueblesonline.es/img/cms/salon-y-comedor_1.jpg">hasta</a> la (...)

Answer (score 0):

https://gist.github.com/fly304625/baa9d1d98d26c507a5b0731d00d04c2a - this example only looks at Deepl tags, not all other tags indiscriminately. Some tags may need to be preserved for certain purposes.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).